# Can I exclude unnecessary imports after import all modules?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` package for GUI programming.

Since I don't know what modules are in need during coding, I usually import all. (by typing `from tkinter import *`)

But I found this could cause a problem when I turned a `.py` file into `.exe` file by using `pyinstaller`. The result file size was too large.

To reduce the file size, I'm trying to edit the `.py` file by excluding unnecessary imported modules. There are lots of unused imports confirmed by pylint(it just warned me when I run `.py` file in terminal on Visual Studio Code). But how should I type the code to exclude these imports?

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: The obvious and universal answer is to not do wildcard imports. You can't have missed the warnings telling you to avoid this antipattern.

Comment: I'm using VScode.

Comment: Even if you only use certain objects from a module, python must still import the full contents of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While importing from other modules its always better to import only the classes and functions that you need or else your program could face problems like taking a lot of time to run the program and takes up a lot of storage space etc.

To only `import` the classes and functions you need you can use

`from module_name import function_name, class_name`

Or else you can `import` `tkinter` itself and use the module name to access the classes and functions in it like this

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
```

To know more about modules you can check the documentation [Modules - Python 3.9.0](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules). And for `tkinter` tutorials you can checkout [Tkinter Tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

Comment: Is tkinter a class name or a module name?

Comment: @donghoonlee It's a module